# Can log likelihood funcion be positive

Tags: expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, likelihood

I have a mixture data. I used EM to estimate the model parameters. When I calculate  the log likelihood function, I found that the values is positive. So, is that ok. Can the log likelihood function be positive?

To be more clear:

$ll = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\log(\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} f(x_n;\theta_{k}))$

Comment: To my understanding, likelihood function is usually a product of probabilities and log-likelihood is a sum of logs. Because probabilities are less than 1, theirs logs should be less than 0. And because you sum those logs, you should get a negative number.

Comment: The comment above is wrong. The likelihood function of continuous parameters (such as your case, I guess) is based on probability *densities*, which can be greater than 1 depending on the domain and the density, so the log likelihood can occasionally be positive. Still, you should check that everything else is correct.

Comment: yes, my density is continuous. '

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply *(just summarizing the comments)*:

- when using probabilities (**discrete** outcome), the log likelihood is the sum of logs of probabilities all smaller than 1, thus it is always negative
- when using probability densities (**continuous** outcome), the log likelihood is the sum of logs of densities that can be greater than 1, thus is can be positive.

Comment: If all the discrete probability is in a single outcome, log-likelihood would be 0 rather than negative.